# List all activated notifications in a ListView

Tags: java, android, list, notifications, push-notification

I can't delete notifications that I haven't created.  I know it, but can I list all the notifications (the text mainly) to put them in a `ListView` or another control?

Thanks

Comment: You need to put some code up and re word your question. This isn't enough of a description

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how to start to program it......I want to catch the text of all notifications (messages push-up) and manage them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a perfect example with accessibility API :

https://github.com/ograycode/NotificationWatcher/

but I'm asking for getting all information about notifications, not only package and text,...

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting API Level 18+, you can use a [`NotificationsListenerService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) for this. Note that you need the special `BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission.

```
 <service android:name=".NotificationListener"
          android:label="@string/service_name"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

You can use the [`NotificationListenerService.getActiveNotifications()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications%28%29) method to get all current notifications.

If you want to support this on API level 17 or less then you can use the accessibility API to read notifications, but it's more complicated.